# How to reverse the default color pallete in ggplot fill aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

My code is:

```
library(geobr)
shape_br <- geobr::read_state()

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(shape_br)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill = code_region))+
  theme_test()
```

I would like to change the direction of the color scale. However, when I add scale_fill_hue(direction = -1), or similar, I get the following error:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

I can't find the right name of the layer to change the direction with the default pallete.

Edit: this is example data. I do not want to make the response variable a factor.

Comment: It sounds as if `code_region` is numeric and being treated as a continuous variable. To have it treated as discrete, try `aes(fill = factor(code_region))`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `code_region` is an integer, so `ggplot` treats it as a continuous variable, whereas `scale_fill_hue` is for discrete variables. The obvious solution is to map to the `name_region`, which is both discrete *and* informative.

```r
ggplot(shape_br) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = name_region)) +
  theme_test() +
  scale_fill_hue("region", direction = -1)
```

[image]

If you want a reversed hue palette on a continuous scale (such as `code_region`), you could do

```r
ggplot(shape_br) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = code_region)) +
  theme_test() +
  scale_fill_gradientn("region", colours = rev(scales::hue_pal()(5)))
```

[image]